# How do you call a function within its function among 4 inner classes

Tags: python, class, oop

```
class Algorithms:
    class SearchAlgorithms:
        class RecursiveBinarySearch:

            def RecursiveBinarySearchAlgo(List, Target):
                '''
                Return true value if it exists and a false if it doesn't
                '''

                # If the length of the List is equal to 0 : return False
                if len(List) == 0:
                    return False

                # Else if the list is not empty
                else:
                    Midpoint = (len(List))//2

                    # IF the Midpoint value within the list is equal to Target value: return true
                    if List[Midpoint] == Target:
                        return True
                    else:
                        if List[Midpoint] < Target:
                            return Algorithms.SearchAlgorithm.RecursiveBinarySearch.RecursiveBinarySearchAlgo(List[Midpoint + 1:], Target)
                        else:
                            return Algorithms.SearchAlgorithm.RecursiveBinarySearch.RecursiveBinarySearchAlgo(List[:Midpoint], Target)    

            def Verify(Result):
                print("Target found: ", Result)

            Numbers = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]

            # Test Cases 1
            Result = RecursiveBinarySearchAlgo(Numbers, 12)
            Verify(Result)
 
            # Test Case 2
            Result = RecursiveBinarySearchAlgo(Numbers, 5)
            Verify(Result)
```

I am getting a name error that the class is not defined `name 'Algorithms' is not defined`.

I tried entering init function with each class with self. But I am still getting the same error

the program should result in:

```
Target found : True
target found: False
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. I can't understand the intended purpose of the code. In particular, I can't understand why these classes exist in the first place. What do you believe is the purpose of a class?

Comment: I am still very unsure of classes but as of now im just using classes to better organize my code more for notetaking really. Instead of creating a file for each data structure i create a class to organize into categories really to better understand the function and test.

Comment: "I am getting a name error that the class is not defined name'Algorithms' is not defined." This happens because the test code is inside the class definitions, so those classes do not exist yet when you try to use them. It should not be written this way.

Comment: "but as of now im just using classes to better organize my code more for notetaking really" They are **completely inappropriate for this purpose**. The reason to create a class is to **define your own data type**. Anyway, voting to close as a typo. (For future reference, please read [mre] and https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/.)

Comment: Oh yes i completely agree and understand classes in this case is unneeded. But like mentioned I used inner class to better organize my code really not for submission but for notes compiling everything into 1 file

Comment: I understand but is there no method i can do to fix the error?

Comment: I don't see any answers here all offensive comments instead of giving advice. For example instead of using "This is not what Python classes are for." kind of arguments please give more details. Explain the reason why those classes aren't for this, he/she is a newbie people!

Comment: This is probably like 100 lines of code I just showed this error but within this file i have around 800lines in between each classes so this also may be hard to explain but i do know this is not how you use classes i understand that again its just for my own use as notes, But my question is how can i call the function RecursiveBinarySearchAlgo within its own function between inner classes

Comment: `Algorithms` doesn't exist yet, you are trying to use it in the body of the class, but that name hasn't been assigned to yet. Look, you've already stated you understand that this isn't how you use classes. So I don't know why you *insist* on doing that. I really suggest you [read through the official tutorial on class definitions](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html)

Comment: @veysiertekin there is nothing offensive being stated in the comments. Perhaps you can say people are being curt. But frankly, precisely the reasons why this doesn't work, and the use-case for when classes *should* be used, has already been mentioned in these comments.

Comment: @Dhruv one thing you *could* do here is try to unnest all the driver code to the top level of the module, but you are going to have to keep using the fully qualified names, like you do here: `Algorithms.SearchAlgorithm.RecursiveBinarySearch.RecursiveBinarySearchAlgo` but with the driver code. Or perhaps just move it to the level of `SearchAlgorithms`.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know why within inner class we cannot call method directly, but as @juanpa.arrivillaga suggested moving to one level up and using an instance of inner class works in addition to `self` keyword on methods:

```
class Algorithms:
    class SearchAlgorithms:
        class RecursiveBinarySearch:

            def RecursiveBinarySearchAlgo(self, List, Target):
                '''
                Return true value if it exists and a false if it doesn't
                '''

                # If the length of the List is equal to 0 : return False
                if len(List) == 0:
                    return False

                # Else if the list is not empty
                else:
                    Midpoint = (len(List))//2

                    # IF the Midpoint value within the list is equal to Target value: return true
                    if List[Midpoint] == Target:
                        return True
                    else:
                        if List[Midpoint] < Target:
                            return self.RecursiveBinarySearchAlgo(List[Midpoint + 1:], Target)
                        else:
                            return self.RecursiveBinarySearchAlgo(List[:Midpoint], Target)

            def Verify(self, Result):
                print("Target found: ", Result)

        rbs = RecursiveBinarySearch()
        Numbers = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]

        # Test Cases 1
        Result = rbs.RecursiveBinarySearchAlgo(Numbers, 12)
        rbs.Verify(Result)

        # Test Case 2
        Result = rbs.RecursiveBinarySearchAlgo(Numbers, 5)
        rbs.Verify(Result)
```

If you don't want to create an instance in that case you can use `@classmethod` annotation as well:

```
class Algorithms:
    class SearchAlgorithms:
        class RecursiveBinarySearch:

            @classmethod
            def RecursiveBinarySearchAlgo(cls, List, Target):
                '''
                Return true value if it exists and a false if it doesn't
                '''

                # If the length of the List is equal to 0 : return False
                if len(List) == 0:
                    return False

                # Else if the list is not empty
                else:
                    Midpoint = (len(List))//2

                    # IF the Midpoint value within the list is equal to Target value: return true
                    if List[Midpoint] == Target:
                        return True
                    else:
                        if List[Midpoint] < Target:
                            return cls.RecursiveBinarySearchAlgo(List[Midpoint + 1:], Target)
                        else:
                            return cls.RecursiveBinarySearchAlgo(List[:Midpoint], Target)

            def Verify(Result):
                print("Target found: ", Result)

        Numbers = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]

        # Test Cases 1
        Result = RecursiveBinarySearch.RecursiveBinarySearchAlgo(Numbers, 12)
        RecursiveBinarySearch.Verify(Result)

        # Test Case 2
        Result = RecursiveBinarySearch.RecursiveBinarySearchAlgo(Numbers, 5)
        RecursiveBinarySearch.Verify(Result)
```